# Establish a variable inside a driver expression

Tags: python, drivers

I'm quite new to python and drivers. I'm writing a rather complicated scripted expression inside the driver-area and I need to repeatedly use a long number sequence. Would it be possible to first store this number inside a new variable and then refer to that variable instead of the number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The driver namespace**

Can add functions and constants to the driver namespace

```
import bpy

def func(a, b, c):
    return a * b * c

m = 9.4443299912

bpy.app.driver_namespace["f"] = func
bpy.app.driver_namespace["m"] = m
```

Run the script above, (*copy & paste into text editor hit **Run Script** button,*)  to make the new members available to the driver namespace. To make it autorun when file is loaded, give the text block a py extension and check the **Register** checkbox on RHS of text editor header

[image]

Can now consider `m` in a driver expression to be a named constant like `pi` and `e`.

Use in a driver expression like `f(m, m, m)` Can be typed directly into a field by preceding with a hash `#` character.  Once the expression is a driver (purple) on editing expression there is no longer a need for `#`.

[image]

There are a number of functions and properties etc already defined to the namespace, a sample of python console output.

```
>>> for k, v in bpy.app.driver_namespace.items():
...     k, v
...     
('asin', <built-in function asin>)
('asinh', <built-in function asinh>)
('atan', <built-in function atan>)
...
('pi', 3.141592653589793)
('e', 2.718281828459045)
...
('f', <function func at 0x7f8f18d34c80>)
('m', 9.4443299912)
('frame', 1.0)
```

Where `frame` is the `context.scene.frame_current`.

EDIT: would like to see a "*sub expression*" driver variable type where you could do this for scalars, or using other defined variables.  Fitting everything into the scripted expression can be a PITA.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good answer. I would like to have just one clarification due to my lack of experience: would you add the first part of your answer directly to the expression-field of the scripted expression, or do I need to establish it in a separate python file?

Comment: @Antti edited answer, possibly the easiest solution is to make the file autorun  on load.

Comment: If you prefer not to use a separate file, consider `(lambda m: m * m * m)(9.4443299912)`.